# How to not escape strings using MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

Using `pymysql` (a `MySQLdb` alternative), I was wondering what was the better way to do string replacement for things like database or field names. E.g.: we want to create a database and it's name comes from a variable (`dbname = "test"`).

```py
c.execute("CREATE DATABASE `test`;")
```

#### Idea 1

This doesn't work because of the added quotes.

```py
c.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s;", (dbname,))
```

#### Idea 2

This is vulnerable to sql injection.

```py
c.execute("CREATE DATABASE `{}`;".format(dbname))
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: No. That's why this is not usually done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to parameterise identifiers such as table or database names, so the only possible way to go is to perform some checks that the name is safe and then use string concatenation.

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html), quoted identifiers can contain any Unicode character from `U+0001` to `U+FFFF`.  The `NUL` character and supplementary characters from `U+10000` onwards are not permitted, so you will need to check for them in any given name and raise an exception if any are found.  If the name contains a backtick itself, you must escape it by doubling.  (Alternatively, you could choose to raise an exception if the identifier contains any backticks.)

Additionally, identifiers cannot be empty, although I'm struggling to see where the MySQL documentation points that out.

So, a suitable function to sanitise an identifier could look something like the following (I'll leave it up to you to fill in the details):

```
def sanitise_identifier(name):
    # raise exception if name is empty or not a string
    # raise exception if name contains NUL chars
    # raise exception if name contains Unicode supplementary characters (U+10000 onwards)
    return name.replace("`", "``")
```

Then you would use it as follows:

```
c.execute("CREATE DATABASE `{}`;".format(sanitise_identifier(dbname)))
```